# how to convert this code in javascript to java

Tags: javascript, java, hash, sha512

i have this code in javascript and i need to convert it to java
but im not expert in javascript.

here the code:

```
function keyGen(mat)
{
        var hash = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($mat)));
        var l = obj.hash.length - 4;
        var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var p3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var motif1 = obj.hash.substr(p1, 4) ;
        var motif2 = obj.hash.substr(p2, 4) ;
        var motif3 = obj.hash.substr(p3, 4) ;
        var cle = motif1+motif2+motif3 ;
    return cle ;
}
```

for the hash i use the function but i can't to modify it:

```
public static String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String   salt){
        String generatedPassword = null;
            try {
                 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                 md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++){
                    sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                 }
                 generatedPassword = sb.toString();
                } 
               catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
            return generatedPassword;
        }
```

Comment: i just need to convert the keygen function to java but i don't know how to...

Comment: which part don't you understand? also, what is `$mat` ... seems to be a variable not declared anywhere ... and what are the `base64_encode` and `pack` and `sha1` functions - they aren't "standard" javascript functions, so must be declared elsewhere in your code

Comment: $mat :meanes the serial number of student
base64_encode : it's base64 crypto 
in global i generate sha512 function then my problem start from here:
  var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var p3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
        var motif1 = obj.hash.substr(p1, 4) ;
        var motif2 = obj.hash.substr(p2, 4) ;
        var motif3 = obj.hash.substr(p3, 4) ;
how to do this from starting from  get_SHA_512_SecurePassword function

Comment: yes, but why is there an argument called `mat` that is never used. Why do you create a `var hash` that is never used. What is `obj` whose `hash` property you are using in the rest of the code? ... see the answer for the code that I can explain

Comment: `get_SHA_512_SecurePassword` seems to be written in a language other than Javascript - so, how is it at all relevant to your problem?

Comment: yes i want to creat all the code in java languge
so in first code of javascript he make hash for mat veriable than he create rendom number
and substring  ....

Comment: sure, but what is `$met`, what is `obj` - you have the code, you haven't shown what those two things are in the question, I keep saying it, and you keep ignoring these two very important details

Answer (score 2):

```
function keyGen(mat) {
    // seems to get the sha1 of $mat (whatever that is), 
    // converts this sha1 into HEX string
    // encode the hex string into into base64
    // the above is a GUESS, as I don't know what library you are using for these functions
    var hash = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($mat)));

    // length of `obj.hash` - whatever that is
    var l = obj.hash.length - 4;

    // random number between 0 and l + 1
    var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
    // random number between 0 and l + 1
    var p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;
    // random number between 0 and l + 1
    var p3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (l+1)) ;

    // a substring of whatever obj.hash is, from position p1 length 4
    var motif1 = obj.hash.substr(p1, 4) ;
    // a substring of whatever obj.hash is, from position p2 length 4
    var motif2 = obj.hash.substr(p2, 4) ;
    // a substring of whatever obj.hash is, from position p3 length 4
    var motif3 = obj.hash.substr(p3, 4) ;

    // the string concatenation of the above three strings
    var cle = motif1+motif2+motif3 ;
    // returns this 12 character string
    return cle ;
}
```

Now, all you need to figure out is

- What is `base64_encode`
- what is `pack`
- what is `sha1`
- what is `$mat`
- what is `obj` that you use `obj.hash` from
- why you are creating `hash` and never using it
- why you never use the `mat` argument

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code : i found it ..... thanks all

```
public static String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String   salt){
        String generatedPassword = null;
            try {
                 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                 md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++){
                    sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                 }
            //     String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(sb.toString());
                 generatedPassword = sb.toString();
                } 
               catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
            return generatedPassword;
        }

    public static String keyGen(String Studentpass,String SaltCrypter) {
        String hash=get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(Studentpass,SaltCrypter);

        int  l = hash.length() - 4;
        new Random().nextInt();

        int p1 =  new  Random().nextInt(l) ; 
        int p2 =  new  Random().nextInt(l) ; 
        int p3 =  new  Random().nextInt(l) ; 

        String motif1 = hash.substring(p1, p1+4);
        String motif2 = hash.substring(p2, p2+4);
        String motif3 = hash.substring(p3, p3+4);
        String cle =(motif1+motif2+motif3);
        cle.replace("l", "L").replace("O", "o").replace("I", "i");
        return cle;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = [
    {url: 'http://172.25.38.138:4000/moservice/create1', startTime: '04/11/2022 16:04:15', endTime: '04/11/2022 16:24:15'},
    {url: 'http://172.25.38.138:4000/moservice/create2', startTime: '04/11/2022 16:24:15', endTime: '04/11/2022 16:34:15'},
    {url: 'http://172.25.38.138:4000/moservice/create3', startTime: '04/11/2022 16:34:15', endTime: '04/11/2022 16:54:15'},
    {url: 'http://172.25.38.138:4000/moservice/create4', startTime: '04/11/2022 17:04:15', endTime: '04/11/2022 17:14:15'}
];
let curntTime = new Date()
function getUrl(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let startTime = new Date(arr[i].startTime)
        let endTime = new Date(arr[i].endTime)

        if (curntTime > startTime && curntTime < endTime) {
            console.log(arr[i].url)
        }
    }
}
getUrl(arr)
```

B

Comment: js code convert into java